# HTML File API: getting the text 'onprogress'

Tags: api, file, html, callback, stream

Using the **HTML5 File API**, I wonder if I can process the content of a file on the fly.

I know I can get the content of the file when **onload** is called:

```
function fileLoaded(e)
    {
    alert("content is "+e.target.result);
    }
```

but can I get the current content when **onprogress** is called ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like yes, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-result). The `onprogress` event will fill the `result` property of your `FileReader` as more data is read in. However, as Matt pointed out, if you're only interested in a portion of the file in the first place, only read that section:

```
var blob = file.webkitSlice|mozSlice(startByte, stopByte, contentType);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but look at this [example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) which shows you how to read slices of files.